swiftui Protocol requirements not implemented in swiftui structures
I've been reading swift documentation and apparently protocols force structures, classes or enumerations to implement specific methods or define certain variables.
I've double checked this functionality by typing the following code. In fact, xcode compiler helped me to verify this since it popped up an alert that depicted the following message : "Type MiguelStruc does not conform to protocol Miguels ..."
protocol Miguels {
    func someF()-> Float
}
public struct MiguelStruc{
    var miguelVar : String = "hey"

}
extension MiguelStruc: Miguels{

}


Now, while I was following the official swiftUI drawing paths and shapes tutorial I encountered this particular chain of code: (https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes)
        Path { path in

        }
        .fill(.black)


By pressing command + click on the Path {...} instance, I could explore the Swiftui documentation and, indeed, I noticed that Shape is a protocol
public protocol Shape : Sendable, Animatable, View


which is implemented by the Path structure
extension Path : Shape


question: Why none of the Path extensions content are explicitly implementing any of the Shape protocol requirements? (if you unfold the ellipsis and check the content, you will notice that)

The same situation happens with the LinearGradient structure:
public struct LinearGradient : ShapeStyle, View, Sendable

it conforms to the protocol ShapeStyle, but in the LinearGradient content you don't see any of the ShapeStyle requirements implemented:


Do you realise that SwiftUI is close-source? How SwiftUI is implemented is not public. Xcode is just showing you the "headers" of SwiftUI.

well that can cause some confusions to someone else who is trying to deeply understand the swiftui logic

You can do that in many other ways. I personally find the WWDC videos (like this one) very helpful. What specifically are you trying to understand about SwiftUI? Edit your question to ask about that.

I just wanna corroborate protocol logic does its job in swiftui source code as defined in the documentation. Thanks for letting me know that it's a close source. I'm gonna stick to it.
